# Remove labels with zero values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a piechart from a dictionary and I'm trying to hide the label with a zero value in it. I'm also trying it with a list of values [300, 250, 0, 425] but can't figure out how to the label either. The code below draws a pie chart with 'oil' still present as a label. How can I hide it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'milk': 45, 'water': 25, 'oil': 0}
names = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())

plt.pie(values, labels=names)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you consider filtering out the `0` values?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'milk': 45, 'water': 25, 'oil': 0}
names = [key for key,value in data.items() if value!=0]
values = [value for value in data.values() if value!=0]

plt.pie(values, labels=names)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Or just do the filtering on the dictionary itself: `{key: value for key, value in data.items() if value != 0}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Lambda filter** for that purpose:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'milk': 45, 'water': 25, 'oil': 0}
data = dict(filter(lambda elem: elem[1]!= 0, data.items()))
names = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())

plt.pie(values, labels=names)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'milk': 45, 'water': 25, 'oil': 0}
data_without_zero = {k:v for k,v in data.items() if v>0}
names = list(data_without_zero.keys())
values = list(data_without_zero.values())

plt.pie(values, labels=names)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unpacking and `zip` can get you both components compactly:

```py
data = {'milk': 45, 'water': 25, 'oil': 0}
lbls, vals = zip(*((k,v) for k,v in data.items() if v>0))

plt.pie(vals, labels=lbls)
```

(I'm assuming that `plt.pie` is happy to accept tuples)